# JSF best practices : One form for the whole application or a few smaller forrms?

Tags: jsf

What is the best practice in JSF , to create one main `<h:form>` in template for example and put all content inside or to have a few forms for each parts, for example if we have two logical blocks of code on the page we should have wrapped these blocks in 2 separate forms ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an overly broad question, and it as well has nothing to di with JSF. It is a question of HTML understanding and design.

If you abstract away all of the JSF details, you'll find out that the rendered component is a plain HTML `<form>`. To recall the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html), a form is:

> a section of a document containing normal content, markup, special elements called controls (checkboxes, radio buttons, menus, etc.), and labels on those controls. Users generally "complete" a form by modifying its controls (entering text, selecting menu items, etc.), before submitting the form to an agent for processing (e.g., to a Web server, to a mail server, etc.)

So ultimately **a whole form** will be submitted to the server. In case of a component-based framework, like JSF, the bound values of components will populate the backing beans with the submitted data, in case there are no errors.

But what data will be submitted? All data that is within a form. So, if you have one global form that means that **all unrelated pieces of information will be collected**: like user credentials, product choices, selection of preferences, etc. And it will be done all at once. Most probably it won't yield the desired functionality, but will produce unexpected results.

The problem there was **mixing of concerns**: one form contained non-related data that *was not designed to be submitted together*. This leaves us with a one-form-per-user-interaction, like one form for user authentication/logout, another form for storing user preferences, yet another one for keeping product choices, etc. One global form also is likely to leave you with nesting forms problem, taking you some time to figure it out.

Regarding the choice of where to put that form, it is as well depending on the logical separation: if you have user login/logout on *every page* it could be placed in master template. Per-view forms are likely to be put in template client. Moreover, you'll find it convenient to sometimes put them side-by-side to distinguish the functionality.

Also, form may alter the expected behaviour. One final example: user choice of products. Consider two cases.

The first one:

```
<h:form>
    <ui:repeat value="#{bean.purchasedProducts}" var="product">
        <h:outputText value=#{product.name}/>
        <h:inputText value=#{product.quantity}/>
        <h:commandButton value="Change"/>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

The second one:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.purchasedProducts}" var="product">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value=#{product.name}/>
        <h:inputText value=#{product.quantity}/>
        <h:commandButton value="Change"/>
    </h:form>
</h:dataTable>
```

While the first example will update *all products*, the second one will update *only the relevant product*.

Finally, there is no 'best practice' or 'universal solution'. I think that it's best to depart from **separation of concerns** when designing an HTML document.

And, yes, I'm voting to close the question.